# How to check for equality in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, scripting

I am trying to find files with a specific date, but my equality isn't working as I think it is supposed to. Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

chdir /d T:

FOR /r %%i IN (*) do (
   echo %%i

   set FileDate=%%~ti
   echo Date: !FileDate!

   set year=!FileDate:~6,4!  
   echo year: !year!

   if !year! == 2009 (
      echo is 2009
   ) else (
      echo not 2009
   )
)
```

And when I run it, I get the following output:

```
T:\SomeFile.txt
Date: 09/11/2009 02:51 PM
year: 2009
not 2009
```

Can somebody please explain to me why the year is printing as 2009, but is not being considered as 2009 by the if check? Thanks and sorry for my batch-file noobery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the `==` comparison operator which means string comparison, you could use the `EQU` operator -- if you have the command extensions enabled (see `if /?` and also `cmd /?`):

```
if !year! EQU 2009
```

This does numeric comparison, so whitespaces around either of the values have no effect.

---

However, to avoid any whitespaces to become part of variable values (in this case `year` contains two trailing spaces), you should use the following syntax of `set`:

```
set "year=!FileDate:~6,4!"
```

Since the quotes `""` are around the entire expression, they do not become part of the value.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a whitespace issue.

On this line you have additional whitespace at the end which is being added to the variable.

```
set year=!FileDate:~6,4!
```

Comment: ... so, in order to avoid this problem, it is convenient to enclose in quotes both the variable and the value: `set "year=!FileDate:~6,4!"  `

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with (add /a):

> set /a year=!FileDate:~6,4!

You can refer to:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting

Good luck ^^/